# mkdir -p doesn't work in package.json script on Windows

Tags: node.js, package.json, mkdir

Say, we have a React app, and there's a script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "create-images-dir": "mkdir -p distrib/images"
}
```

If to run this script via `npm run create-images-dir` on Linux, it works fine. But trying to run it on Windows environment in *git-bash* or *Cygwin* terminal, I'm getting this error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Same error with setting `--parents` instead of `-p`. Without `-p` parameter, it works, so it stumbles on `-p`. But at the same time, the command from script works fine if typed manually in terminal:

```
mkdir -p distrib/images
```

For me, it looks like some symbol escaping occurs when command is translated from script to execution, or different processing of nested directories on Windows, but I have no idea what exactly it is. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: After installing the _mkdirp_ package, I faced another shell-related issues. Eventually, I ended up with specifying _git-bash_ as shell for npm, that did the trick:

`npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`.

This setting works globally, and thus can affect another projects, but it is all right for my case. I mark the comment from @dmfay as answer, as it arrived first and exactly addresses the initial question. @Arprit-Agarwal, thank you for info about `os` parameter.

Comment: @Arpit Agarwal, I really apologize for making typo in your name. I read it wrong initially, and realized it just now. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why the [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) package exists -- add it as a dev dependency and use the binary `mkdirp` in your script instead of the platform-specific `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the correct syntax to create directory recursively is:

```
mkdir -p distrib/images
```

On Windows you don't have to specify `-p`.

You can use [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) package as suggested by @dmfay or use [os](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#os)
in your `package.json` to not include `-p` when on windows.

Comment: Hi @Arprit, thank you for comment and information about `os` parameter, I didn't know about it. But `os` won't work for me unfortunately, as seems like it limits platforms where the module or project can be run, while I need run the module on both Linux and Windows.